# My cronjobs are creating the files being executed?

Tags: php, cron

Since a week I've set up 2 cronjobs. One is executed every minute, the other once per night. After checking in via FTP I noticed many files were created. These files are named after the cronjob-files. Atm I've cleaned up 6.000 unwanted files but I'm curious what's wrong?

I'm executing the files via wget and they are stored in the root-folder (at the same level where the public_html dir is located).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `wget` is saving its output as it does by default. You can specify `/dev/null` as the output file, and it will not save anything.

```
wget http://example.com/yourfile.php -O /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didn't knew, I've added -O /dev/null and now no more unwanted files are created! +1 and accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the downloaded files to `/dev/null`, which basically eats all data shoved into it:

```
wget -O /dev/null foo.com
```

`wget` is made to download files. If you want, try looking at `curl`, which may suit your needs a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was the solution. Too bad I can only accept 1 answer, nevertheless +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `-O` option to `wget`, and put `> /dev/null` to the end of your crontab entries, the problem will go away.

`wget` downloads the file you point it to, but `-O` writes the file to STDOUT instead of disk, and `> /dev/null` blackholes the data.